# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles-- Yammer integration in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, yammer

I am integrating yammer with sharepoint,creating yammer webpart.
I have configured it in sharepoint 2010 Foundation.
When i create yammer webpart, It is showing something like

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' at
>   Yammer.SharePoint.Framework.SPUserProfileManager.GetProfile(String
>   accountName, SPSite site) at
>   Yammer.SharePoint.Framework.YammerSharePointContentStore.GetUserEmail()
>   at
>   Yammer.SharePoint.Framework.DefaultYammerSettingsManager.EnsureYammerSession(String
>   networkId) at
>   Yammer.SharePoint.WebParts.YammerAppsWebPart.CreateChildControls()

How can i resolve this issue.
Should i need to load any assembly? Or pass my credentials anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem is you haven't deployed the Yammer for SharePoint WSP correctly.

Instead you try http://success.yammer.com/integrations/sharepoint/ this link in which select the online option

INSTALLATION::

1 . Download the web part from success.yammer.com.

1. From Site Actions, click Site Settings.
2. From Galleries, click Solutions.
3. Click Library.
4. Click Solutions.
5. Click Upload.
6. Browse to the Yammer for SharePoint Online wsp file.
7. Click Activate.

After which you can easily add the web part for Yammer.

Prerequisites: your service account needs to be configured with Yammer credentials.